# Brackets Git error - no clone & init commands available

Tags: adobe-brackets

I face to an issue with Brackets and Brackets Git that I didn't faced with two previous installations on my other Apple devices.

When I open a new empty folder in Brackets, automatically Brackets Git shows the following error message:

```
Error: fatal: neither this nor any of its parent directories is a git repository: .git
```

I'm not allow to **Clone** or **Init** the folder as the two commands don't appears.

I tried to open folders that I worked with previously and that are already on my GitHub account, all is work well. Brackets Git IU shows all the available commands.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not include "thanks" or similar in your questions. See here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts and here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it